# Determine the set of cut vertices, bridges and number of connected components.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

In the following graphs, determine the set of cut vertices,
bridges and number of connected components when removing cut vertices or bridges:

a) Complete graphs

b) Bipartite graphs

c) Path

d) Cycles

e) Stars

I have an idea of the exercise... For (a) we deduce that $K_n$ does not have cut vertices, consequently, it does not have bridges; every edge of $K_n$ is in a cycle. For (c) we have $n−2$ cut vertices and $n−1$ bridges. For (d) A cut vertex is a single vertex that, when removed, disconnects the graph or component that the vertex belongs to. In a loop of length $n$, removing any vertex will leave us with a path of length $n−1$. So no cycle has a cut vertex. For the rest, I have no idea.

Comment: @CAT: Note that $K_2$ does have a bridge, though it has no cut vertex; what you said about (a) works for $n\ge 3$, however. (c) and (d) are correct. The star graph $K_{1,n}$ has no bridges if $n\ge 2$, and the central vertex is its only cut vertex.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I appreciate your comment.